# Returning rows in a dataframe to a list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and a few 1000 rows with text data. One column contains floats that represent time in ascending order (0, 0.45, 0.87, 1.10 etc). From this  I want to build a new dataframe that contains only all the rows where these time values are closest to the integers x = 0,1,2,3......etc

Here on Stackoverflow I found an answer to a very similar question, answer posted by DSM. The code is essentially this, modified (hopefully) to give -the- closest number to x, df is my data frame.

```
df.loc[(df.ElapsedTime-x).abs().argsort()[:1]]
```

This seems to essentially do what I need for one x value but I can't figure out how to iterate this over the -entire- data frame to extract -all- rows where the column value is closest to x = 0,1,2,3....in ascending order. This code gives me a data frame, there must be a way to loop this and append the resulting data frames to get the desired result?

I have tried this:

```
L=[]
for x in np.arange(len(df)):
    L.append(df.loc[(df.ElapsedTime-x).abs().argsort()[:1]])
L
```

L, in principle has the right rows but it is a messy list and it takes a long time to execute because for loops are not a great way to iterate over a data frame. I'd prefer to get a data frame as the result.

I feel I am missing something trivial.

Not sure how to post the desired dataframe.

Lets say the timevalues are (taken from my dataframe):

```
0.00,0.03,0.58,1.59,1.71,1.96,2.21,2.33,2.46,2.58,2.7,2.83,2.95,3.07
```

The values grabbed for 0,1,2,3 would be 0, .58, 1.96, 2.95

@beroe: if the numbers are 0.8, 1.1, 1.4, 2.8, in this case 1.1 should be grabbed for 1 and 1.4 should be grabbed for 2. If as an example the numbers are 0.5 1.5 2.5. While I think it is unlikely this will happen in my data I think it would be fine to grab 1.5 as 1 and 2.5 as 2. In this application I don't think it is that critical, although I am not sure how I would implement this.

Please let me know if anyone needs any additional info.

Comment: Please post an example DataFrame and the desired result.

Comment: What do you want to happen if two values are close to the same integer, but none close to the next integer in line? e.g., `0.8, 1.1, 1.4, 2.8` -- Do you want the 1.4 to be grabbed for 2, although it is closer to 1? Will there ever be values where the same value is the closest to two different integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how fast this would be, but you could round the times to get "integer" candidates, take the absolute value of the difference to give yourself a way to find the closest, then sort by difference, and then `groupby` the integer time to return just the rows that are close to integers:

```
# setting up my fake data 
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['ElapsedTime']=pd.Series([0.5, 0.8, 1.1, 1.4, 1.8, 2.2, 3.1])

# To use your own data set, set df = Z, and start here...
df['bintime'] = df.ElapsedTime.round()
df['d'] = abs(df.ElapsedTime - df.bintime)
dfindex = df.sort('d').groupby('bintime').first()
```

For the fake time series defined above, the contents of `dfindex` is:

```
         ElapsedTime    d
bintime                  
0                0.5  0.5
1                1.1  0.1
2                1.8  0.2
3                3.1  0.1
```

Comment: Beroe: The ElapsedTime column in dfindex is exactly the times I want to extract. What would be the best way to now extract the corresponding columns in my Z dataframe? I'd be tempted to try something along the lines of making a new dataframe for which: Z['ElapsedTime'] = dfindex['ElapsedTime'], am I on the right track here?

Comment: Just do the same process using your data frame instead of `df` and the columns should come along with everything in the`groupby` step. Or say `df = Z` at the start and try as written.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is the best way to extract the corresponding rows, not columns.

Comment: The solution seems so trivial now that I see it......I appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: @Arne great. Did you try the `nearest` answer by @piRsquared too? Both are straightforward but that seemed pretty clever.

Comment: I did try that as well but it seemed the numbers where not what I expected. Also, I found it easier to understand what your code is actually doing. I really am pretty new to Python, so what is maybe obvious is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(5000), np.random.rand(5000) * 100).sort_index()

s.head()

0.002587    3007
0.003418    4332
0.060767    2045
0.125182    3179
0.134487    4614
dtype: int64
```

Get all integers to get closest to with:

```
idx = (s.index // 1).unique()
```

Then reindex with `method='nearest'`

```
s.reindex(idx, method='nearest').head()

0.0    3912
1.0    3617
2.0    2574
3.0     811
4.0     932
dtype: int64
```